# how to split one value from sql database into two rows

Tags: sql

how to split one value from sql database and devide into two rows (one row set 1000000, one row is the balance) Others less than 1000000.or any idea using coldfusion . Thanks in advance.

Example

```
No. Code    Name    Account No  Total
1   123    black    123456789   160000.00
2   124    red      111111222     5200.00
3   124    blue     444555666   121000.00
```

I want This result

```
No. Code    Name    Account No  Total
1   123    black    123456789   100000.00
2   123    black    123456789    60000.00
3   124    red      111111222     5200.00
4   124    blue     444555666   100000.00
5   124    blue     444555666    21000.00
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm lost.  Both 260,000 and 400,000 are less than 1,000,000, so I have not idea why they are split.

Comment: Can you give an example what happen if the total > `1000000`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to insert a new row:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (CODE, NAME, ACCOUNT_NO, TOTAL) 
   SELECT 
      CODE, 
      NAME,
      ACCOUNT_NO,
      TOTAL MOD 100000 AS NEW_TOTAL
   FROM TABLE
      WHERE TOTAL > 100000;
```

That command will insert the second row. Now you need to fix the first row.

```
UPDATE TABLE
    SET TOTAL = TOTAL - (TOTAL MOD 100000)
    WHERE TOTAL > 100000;
```